# Where does this matrix, $\begin{pmatrix}0 & \mathcal{B}_{z} \\-\mathcal{B}_{z} & 0\end{pmatrix}$ come from in the Lorentz force law?

Tags: vectors, determinant, matrix-equations, cross-product, electromagnetism

> The anisotropic conductivity of the Hall configuration.
> We will only explore the case of perpendicular electric and magnetic fields, throughout the course, with the convention that:  $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{E}}= \left(\mathcal{E}_{x}, \mathcal{E}_{y},0 \right)$ and $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}} = (0,0,\mathcal{B}_{z})$. We can thus write down the steady-state transport equation for a particular carrier type, following Eqn. $10.3$. We will do this for our definition of mobility as $ = /^*$. If you remember from Lecture 5, we stated that mobility should be positive valued, while $ = \pm $ for electrons and holes. We can write this as a 2D matrix equation since we know carrier motion will be in the $$, $$ plane.
> $$\begin{pmatrix}v_{dx} \\v_{dy} \\ \end{pmatrix}=\frac{q}{e}\mu\left[\begin{pmatrix}_{x}\\_{y}\end{pmatrix}+\color{red}{\begin{pmatrix}0 & \mathcal{B}_{z} \\-\mathcal{B}_{z} & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v_{dx} \\ v_{dy}\end{pmatrix}}\right]$$ where $v_{dx},v_{dy}$ are components of the drift velocity.

My question is a rather simple one, I would just like to know why the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & \mathcal{B}_{z} \\-\mathcal{B}_{z} & 0\end{pmatrix}$ takes this form with zeros on the leading diagonal (and why one of the elements is negative). Equation $10.3$ mentioned in the quote above (from Imperial College London Dept. of Physics) is $$\boldsymbol{\mathcal{v}}_{d}=\frac{q\tau}{m^*}\left(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{E}}+\boldsymbol{\mathcal{v}}_{d}\times\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}}\right)\tag{1}$$

I know that if we have a cross product of two vectors $\boldsymbol{A}$ & $\boldsymbol{B}$, then, $$\boldsymbol{A}\times\boldsymbol{B}=\begin{vmatrix}\hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\ A_x & A_y & A_z \\ B_x & B_y & B_z \\ \end{vmatrix}$$

Specializing to the case of the cross-product in $(1)$ gives $$\boldsymbol{\mathcal{v}}_{d}\times\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}}=\begin{pmatrix}v_{dx}\\v_{dy}\\0\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\B_z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\ v_{dx} & v_{dy} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & B_z \\ \end{vmatrix}= \color{red}{B_z\left(v_{dy}\hat i-v_{dx}\hat j\right)}$$

But how are (the two red parts equal) $${B_z\left(v_{dy}\hat i-v_{dx}\hat j\right)}={\begin{pmatrix}0 & \mathcal{B}_{z} \\-\mathcal{B}_{z} & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v_{dx} \\ v_{dy}\end{pmatrix}}?$$

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti Hi, thanks for your response, I'm still a bit confused though, how do I use these column vectors to reach the matrix for the magnetic field?

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti Why do you keep writing these brackets as raised to $T$, and what is $T$?

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti Thanks for the clarification, I'm still totally confused, sorry. I didn't know you could write column vectors like that. Could you perhaps show intermediate steps that lead to prove that ${B_z\left(v_{dy}\hat i-v_{dx}\hat j\right)}={\begin{pmatrix}0 & \mathcal{B}_{z} \\-\mathcal{B}_{z} & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v_{dx} \\ v_{dy}\end{pmatrix}}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the LHS of your last equation,
$$
{B_z\left(v_{dy}\hat i-v_{dx}\hat j\right)}=B_z\,v_{dy}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}
-B_z\,v_{dx}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}B_z\,v_{dy}\\-B_z v_{dx}\end{pmatrix};
$$
on the RHS,
$$
{\begin{pmatrix}0 & \mathcal{B}_{z} \\
-\mathcal{B}_{z} & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v_{dx} \\ v_{dy}\end{pmatrix}}
=\begin{pmatrix}B_z\,v_{dy}\\-B_z\,v_{dx}\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
B_z\left(v_{dy}\hat i-v_{dx}\hat j\right)=\begin{pmatrix}0 & \mathcal{B}_{z} \\
-\mathcal{B}_{z} & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v_{dx} \\ v_{dy}\end{pmatrix}.
$$